# Problem in fetching the updated data in react app

Tags: reactjs

I am updating the data in my database here `fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/'+book_id+'/'+msg+'/addchat/').then(response => response.json()).then(result => console.log(result)).catch(err => console.log(err))` and in next step i am fetching the updated data but the problem is its not fetching the latest updated data. **for example**
I sended 'Hello' it has been sended but not fetched in chat display and next text i send 'World' then the text hello appears in my chat display but not 'world' .

```
const Yourbooks = () => {
    const send = (book_id,msg) => {
        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/'+book_id+'/'+msg+'/addchat/').then(response => response.json()).then(result => console.log(result)).catch(err => console.log(err))
        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user_booklist/')
        .then(data => data.json())
        .then(data => {
            setBook({ books: data })
    })
    }
    const [book,setBook] =useContext(BookContext)
    return(
    book.books.map(book => 
        <div className='your_books' key={book.bookdetails.book_id}>
        <div className='bookcont'>
            <div className='bookimg'>
                <img src={book.bookdetails.book_img} className='boimg'></img>
            </div>
            <div className='bookdet'>
                <span className='bookname'>{book.bookdetails.book_name}</span>
                <span className='book_added_data'>{book.bookdetails.time}</span>
            </div>
            <button className='delete'>Delete</button>
        </div>
        <div className='comment'>
            <div className='chat_container' id={book.bookdetails.book_id+'_container'}>
                <div className='chat_msg'>
                {/* {console.log(book.status.chats)} */}
                <Chats chat={book.status.chats}></Chats>
                </div>
            
            <div className='text_send'><input type='text' className='msg' id={book.bookdetails.book_id}></input>
            <input type='button' className='sendbutton' value='send' onClick={() => send(book.bookdetails.book_id,document.getElementById(book.bookdetails.book_id).value)}></input>
            </div></div>
            <button
             className='show_hide_char' onClick={(e)=>{
                document.getElementById(book.bookdetails.book_id+'_container').style.height=document.getElementById(book.bookdetails.book_id+'_container').style.height!='auto'? 'auto':'0px';
                e.target.innerHTML=e.target.innerHTML=='Show Comment'? 'Hide Comment':'Show Comment' 
            }}>Show Comment</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    ))

        }      
export default Yourbooks;
```

**Can someone help me in solving this problem?**

Comment: setState() should be treated asynchronously — in other words, do not always expect that the state has changed after calling setState().

Comment: I wouldn't have 2 separate fetch requests. Fetch is asynchronous, so with 2 separate requests that are called 1 after eachother, you might have the second fetch finish before the first one is finished. I would put what you want for the second one, inside the then for the first one

Comment: i tried but it didn't work